# rm removes file then says it does not exist

Tags: bug, apple-diagnostics

Recently, when I remove a file with rm, the file is removed, but I also get the message "No such file or directory" with the same path/filename.  Of course, the message is true, since the file was just removed, but it is unnecessary and didn't happen a few months ago.  And it does not happen **every** time, but at least half.

Is it some system setting, or a bug in recent O.S. versions?

```
WG@MBP ~ % type rm
rm is /bin/rm
```

Comment: What do you have `rm` aliased to?

Comment: There is no alias for `rm` on this system, nor has there ever been.  This is new behavior that started some time this year.  It doesn't always happen, but usually, and when it does, I have not been able to identify a cause.

Comment: Please add the output of `type rm` to your question.